# Apps in Kivy: get values in kv file

Tags: python, kivy

I am new to programming with Kivy, I'm trying to develop a program that collects the number of people in a room.

And my difficulty is to pass values between KV file and the main. I need to get the value of the slider which is in KV file and use it in main.py program

How could it? already I tried several ways that were posted on different topics here on the site but could not. Perhaps because as I have no knowledge in the area did not know apply it right.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder

class ThemeBackground(Screen):
    pass

class myApp(App):

    def build(self):
        root = ScreenManager()
        root.add_widget(ThemeBackground(name='Screen'))
        return root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myApp().run()
```

And Kv file

```
#:import random random.random

<ThemeBackground>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            source: 'data/images/background.jpg'
            size: self.size

    BoxLayout:
        padding: 10
        spacing: 10
        size_hint: 1, None
        pos_hint: {'top': 1}
        height: 44
        Image:
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 24, 24
            source: 'data/logo/kivy-icon-24.png'
        Label:
            height: 24
            text_size: self.size
            color: (1, 1, 1, .8)
            text: 'Kivy 1.9.0.'
            valign: 'middle'

    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        Label:
            text: 'Please enter \nthe number of occupants?'
            bold: True
            font_name: 'data/fonts/DejaVuSans.ttf'
            font_size: 22
            halign: 'center'

        Slider:
            id: slider
            min: 0.0
            max: 15.0
            value: 1.0
            step: 1.0
            orientation: "horizontal"
            width: "38dp"

        Label
            text: ''

        Label
            text: '{}'.format(slider.value)
            halign: 'center'
            valign: 'top'
            bold: True
            text_size: self.size
            font_size: 18

    Button:
        text: 'Enter'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '50sp'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should load the `kv` file in the `build` of your `myApp`:

```
class myApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.load_kv("main.kv")
        return ThemeBackground()
```

You have unneeded `}` in the bottom of `kv` file,the last character, remove it.

```
     height: '50sp'}
```

Preview:
[image]

---

In order to access the values of the slider, add a variable `myslider` to both of python and kv files like this:

**kv**:

```
<ThemeBackground>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    myslider: slider
```

**python**:

```
class ThemeBackground(Screen):
    myslider = ObjectProperty(None)
```

Now you can access the value , min or max by:

```
class myApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.load_kv("kivy.3.kv")
        tb = ThemeBackground() 
        print "value =",tb.myslider.value # <---- value here
        print "min =",tb.myslider.min # <--- min here
        return tb
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @bigOTHER. As the passage of slider values to a variable within the main program, how could I do?